# Not able to edit,add or delete from backend in magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, server-setup

I am able login in back-end and every pages are opening properly. The problem is when I edit,delete or add anything from admin,it shows the correct message "The configuration has been saved" but in actual it is not saving.

I am too much fed up with this problem,,I have uploaded all the files again but problem remains the same.

Can anyone help me please. This requirement is very urgent for me.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: what are the logs saying (var/log)? Do you use a master-slave configuration for your website? If so check maybe you write on the master and the replication to the slave fails.

Comment: Also, check the apache logs. And have you configured a custom admin base URL in the backend?

Answer (score 3):

Have you by any chance forced /index.php/ out of your admin URLs?

If so - reinstate /index.php/ and hopefully everything will start saving again.

This is usually caused by .htaccess tweaks designed to forcefully strip away the index.php from any URL. e.g. mydomain.com/index.php/admin becomes mydomain.com/admin

The culprit normally looks something like the following (or some variation of):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php/(.*)$ http://localhost:8888/$2 [R=301,L]
```

This does a good job of removing the index.php from the URL but unfortunately stops anything saving in the Magento admin (even though you get a success message)!